# How to specify what fields to search in the querytext for Sharepoint Search Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-search

I am working with Sharepoint Search REST API and I am using Sharepoint Search Query Tool for some testing. My current Sharepoint Search Query URL looks like this:

`http://org.sharepoint_sample.com/_api/search/query?querytext='travel+Division:"Div1"'&sourceid='abcdes'&clienttype='PeopleResultsQuery'`

As you can see I am searching for `querytext` `travel` and have a filter that `Division` should be `Div1`. Now what I am trying to do is that it should only search for `travel` in certain specific fields and not all the fields. As in since I am doing `PeopleResultsQuery` and there are fields like `About me`, `interest`, `history` and so on for each person. I want to search for `travel` only in `About me` and `interest`field and not other fields.

In Sharepoint Search Query Tool I see lot of fields but don't know which one could help in achieving this. How can I specify fields on which to search the `querytext`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
querytext='AboutMe:TextValueToMatch'
```

However, it may take a few hours to a few days before changes made to those fields are indexed and available for search.  So you may not see results right away.  And not all fields can handle 'partial' matching, so make sure you're using a complete word match for testing purposes.